# animação de texto

Tags: html, css, animação, vídeo, text

Alguém sabe qual nome da animação de texto do clipe "Alone - Alan walker"? no final "You are not alone" onde as letras se movem e faz uma animação glitch.
Quem souber eu apenas preciso do nome, pois irei fazer no after effects.

Comment: Chama justamente Text Glitch Effect *(o exemplo que vc citou parece que o efeito foi feito só no eixo X)* aqui tem um tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mCkvZJ6_qtE Eu votei para fecha pq não tem a ver com o scopo do StackOverflow. Mas da para fazer algo bem próximo disso só com CSS

Comment: OBS. Se quiser só com CSS ai edite sua pergunta para ela não ser fechada... pois sendo em after effects fatalmente eles a fecharam.

Comment: No css eu sei fazer, mas queria para o after effects mesmo, achei que alguém poderia saber o nome

Comment: Luciana é o mesmo nome o efeito " **Text Glitch Effect** " tem pra CSS, After e Photoshop se quiser. Até no Flash o nome do efeito é o mesmo